# Shiny.setInputValue only works on the 2nd try

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

@yonicd recently created a new R package to generate screenshots of shinyapps (and elements of a shinyapp) and it works well (https://github.com/yonicd/snapper). For another app i'm working on, I wanted to (1) show the snapper screenshot in a modal and then (2) extract the img and save it to disk. In the example below the "Download (snapper)" button works as expect. However, the "Download (shiny)" button fails the first time you click it because "input$img_src" returns NULL. Click it a 2nd time, and it works fine. Of course, I want it to work the first time as well.

I can see in the browser console that the image is available (`$("#screenshot_link_preview img").attr("src");`) but it seems `input$img_src` is not being updated quickly enough. I tried using `sleep` in js and R but no luck. Any suggestions?

Why this custom button? If I can get this to work, it should also be possible to save images server-side using [shinyFiles](https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles) which is ultimately what I need.

EDIT: @Stéphane Laurent solution works great with shinyFiles (development version) and a shiny download button. See
[gist](https://gist.github.com/vnijs/82d4a49448f8cf93e01537c5c8557200) for a full example

```
library(shiny)
# remotes::install_github("yonicd/snapper")
library(snapper)
library(base64enc)
library(png)

js <- '
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("get_img_src", get_img_src);

function get_img_src(message) {
  var img_src = $("#screenshot_link_preview img").attr("src");
  Shiny.setInputValue("img_src", img_src);
}
'

ui <- navbarPage("Snapper app",
  navbarMenu("", icon = icon("save"),
    tabPanel(
      snapper::preview_link(
        "screenshot_link", ui = "body", previewId = "screenshot_link_preview", label = "Take a screenshot",
        opts = config(
          ignoreElements = "function (el) {return el.className === 'dropdown-menu';}"
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("img { max-width: 85% !important; height: auto; }")),
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    snapper::load_snapper()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$screenshot_link, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = "App screenshot",
        span(snapper::snapper_div(id = "screenshot_link_preview")),
        footer = tagList(
          downloadButton("download_screenshot", "Download (shiny)"),
          snapper::download_button(
            ui = "#screenshot_link_preview",
            label = "Download (snapper)",
            filename = "snapper-body.png"
          ),
          modalButton("Cancel"),
        ),
        size = "m",
        easyClose = TRUE
      )
    )
  })

  output$download_screenshot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "radiant-screenshot.png"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      session$sendCustomMessage("get_img_src", "")
      plt <- sub("data:.+base64,", "", input$img_src)
      plt <- png::readPNG(base64enc::base64decode(what = plt))
      png::writePNG(plt, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, using the `onclick` attribute of the download button.

```
library(shiny)
library(snapper)
library(base64enc)
library(png)

js <- '
function get_img_src(){
  var img_src = $("#screenshot_link_preview img").attr("src");
  Shiny.setInputValue("img_src", img_src);
}
'

ui <- navbarPage("Snapper app",
                 navbarMenu("", icon = icon("save"),
                            tabPanel(
                              snapper::preview_link(
                                "screenshot_link", ui = "body", previewId = "screenshot_link_preview", label = "Take a screenshot",
                                opts = config(
                                  ignoreElements = "function (el) {return el.className === 'dropdown-menu';}"
                                )
                              )
                            )
                 ),
                 tags$head(
                   tags$style(HTML("img { max-width: 85% !important; height: auto; }")),
                   tags$script(HTML(js)),
                   snapper::load_snapper()
                 )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$screenshot_link, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = "App screenshot",
        span(snapper::snapper_div(id = "screenshot_link_preview")),
        footer = tagList(
          downloadButton("download_screenshot", "Download (shiny)", 
                         onclick = "get_img_src();"),
          snapper::download_button(
            ui = "#screenshot_link_preview",
            label = "Download (snapper)",
            filename = "snapper-body.png"
          ),
          modalButton("Cancel"),
        ),
        size = "m",
        easyClose = TRUE
      )
    )
  })

  output$download_screenshot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "radiant-screenshot.png"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      plt <- sub("data:.+base64,", "", input$img_src)
      plt <- png::readPNG(base64enc::base64decode(what = plt))
      png::writePNG(plt, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```