# Download plot using jqui_resizable in R shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Sorry for my poor English, I am not a native speaker.

I want to make download button that can download plot resized by jqui_resizable package.
[image]

I read these URLs for make this.
[download a plot without replotting in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618801/download-a-plot-without-replotting-in-r-shiny)
[Shiny.setInputValue only works on the 2nd try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61690502/shiny-setinputvalue-only-works-on-the-2nd-try)

But I have a problem.
Like the second URL above, Shiny.setinputvalue only updates the value on the second run.

This is minimum sample code.
Can someone please modify this code so that the image can be downloaded on the first click?
Or could you please share some information that could help us solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
library(magick)
library(xfun)

js <- 'function get_img_src(){
    var src = document.getElementById("myPlot").childNodes[0].src;
    Shiny.setInputValue("img_src", src);
    }'

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("save_myPlot",onclick="get_img_src();"),
  # plot
  jqui_resizable(plotOutput("myPlot")),
  tags$script(HTML(js))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # downaload handler - save the image
  output$save_myPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
      paste0("plot_", Sys.Date(), ".png") },
    content = function(file) {
      # get image code from URI
      img_src <- gsub("data:.+base64,", "", input$img_src)
      # decode the image code into the image
      img_src <- image_read(base64_decode(img_src))
      # save the image
      image_write(img_src, file)
    })
  
  # plot
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot(
    plot(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

=======================================

(Editted)
This problem does not seem to occur in Windows & Chrome environments.
This is my sessionInfo.

R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.8.so

locale:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5znuP.png) LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=ja_JP.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=ja_JP.UTF-8
[5] LC_MONETARY=ja_JP.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C              LC_PAPER=ja_JP.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=ja_JP.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5znuP.png) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5znuP.png) xfun_0.31        magick_2.7.3     shinyjqui_0.4.1  wordcloud2_0.2.1 shiny_1.7.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5znuP.png) tinytex_0.40       tidyselect_1.1.2   bslib_0.4.0        shinyjs_2.1.0      purrr_0.3.4        lattice_0.20-45
[7] vctrs_0.4.1        generics_0.1.2     htmltools_0.5.3    yaml_2.3.5         utf8_1.2.2         rlang_1.0.3
[13] later_1.3.0        pillar_1.7.0       jquerylib_0.1.4    glue_1.6.2         withr_2.5.0        DBI_1.1.3
[19] lifecycle_1.0.1    fontawesome_0.3.0  htmlwidgets_1.5.4  memoise_2.0.1      fastmap_1.1.0      Cairo_1.6-0
[25] httpuv_1.6.6       parallel_4.0.2     fansi_1.0.3        Rcpp_1.0.8.3       xtable_1.8-4       renv_0.15.5
[31] promises_1.2.0.1   DT_0.23            cachem_1.0.6       RcppParallel_5.1.4 OpenMx_2.20.6      jsonlite_1.8.0
[37] mime_0.12          digest_0.6.29      dplyr_1.0.9        grid_4.0.2         cli_3.3.0          tools_4.0.2
[43] magrittr_2.0.3     sass_0.4.2         tibble_3.1.7       crayon_1.5.1       pkgconfig_2.0.3    MASS_7.3-57
[49] ellipsis_0.3.2     Matrix_1.4-1       shinyBS_0.61.1     lubridate_1.8.0    assertthat_0.2.1   rstudioapi_0.13
[55] R6_2.5.1           compiler_4.0.2

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue, it works fine on my setup (windows / firefox)

Comment: Indeed, it works like this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  
My development environment is RstudioServer on Ubuntu accessed with Chrome, but after reading your comment, I tried it on Windows and Chrome and it works fine.  
This problem seems to depend on the environment, so I will check the environment including the package version.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by myself. I made two dummy download button.
This method may seem like a lot of hassle, but modularization would eliminate the hassle.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
library(shinyjs)
library(magick)
library(xfun)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("save_myPlot","download", icon = icon("download")),
  actionButton("save_myPlot2","download", icon = icon("download"), style = "visibility: hidden;"),
  downloadButton("save_myPlot_hidden",style = "visibility: hidden;"),
  # plot
  jqui_resizable(plotOutput("myPlot")),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # I could not get plot_src with Javascript in Linux environment. However, I found that I could get it by running it twice.
  # Therefore, I was able to solve the problem by inserting two dummy buttons: DL button -> DL button 2 -> real DL button.
  observeEvent(input$save_myPlot,{
    shinyjs::runjs("Shiny.setInputValue('plot_src', document.getElementById('myPlot').childNodes[0].src);
                   document.getElementById('save_myPlot2').click();
                   ")
  })
  observeEvent(input$save_myPlot2,{
    shinyjs::runjs("Shiny.setInputValue('plot_src',document.getElementById('myPlot').childNodes[0].src);
                   document.getElementById('save_myPlot_hidden').click();
                   ")
  })
  # downaload handler - save the image
  output$save_myPlot_hidden <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
      paste0("plot_", Sys.Date(), ".png") },
    content = function(file) {
      # get image code from URI
      plot_src <- gsub("^data.*base64,", "", input$plot_src)
      # decode the image code into the image
      plot_image <- image_read(base64_decode(plot_src))
      # save the image
      image_write(plot_image, file)
    })
  
  # plot
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot(
    plot(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```